# Deterministically hash dictionary

Tags: python, json, hashcode

I need to compute a deterministic hash for a JSON-serializable dictionary.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22003440/3620003) almost does the job, but there are a few problems.

1. If `dict1 == dict2` then I expect `hash_dict(dict1) == hash_dict(dict2)`. However, in Python integers and floats with the same value are equal, but don't have the same string representation.
2. I only want to allow string keys, but the standard `json` module auto-converts numbers in dict-keys to strings.
3. The [`demjson`](https://pypi.org/project/demjson/) library allows a `strict=True` argument when encoding, which would solve point 2. However, unlike `json.dumps` no key-sorting is supported, which is necessary to apply the answer from stackoverflow.

So my clunky solution

1. Recursively converts all ints to floats.
2. Does a strict test-dump with `demjson`.
3. Dumps the data again with `json`.
4. Computes the hash.

Code:

```
import hashlib
import json

import demjson


def _int_to_float(x):
    'Convert integer to float. Traverses lists, tuples and dicts recursively.'
    if isinstance(x, int):
        result = float(x)
    elif isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        result = type(x)(_int_to_float(o) for o in x)
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        result = {
            _int_to_float(k): _int_to_float(v)
            for k, v in x.items()
        }
    else:
        result = x # NOTE that there's no copying here

    return result


def hash_dict(d: dict) -> str:
    # ensure that all keys are strings
    demjson.encode(d, strict=True)
    # convert int to floats
    d = _int_to_float(d)
    # convert to string
    s = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=True)
    # convert to bytes
    b = s.encode('utf-8')
    # hash
    return hashlib.sha1(b).hexdigest()
```

The `_int_to_float` helper function seems to be necessary because [`json.JSONEncoder.default`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) is only called for datatypes that are not supported by default, so a custom `JSONEncoder` subclass, i.e.

```
import json

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, int):
            return float(o)
        return super().default(o)
```

would do nothing.

Is there a less clunky way to solve the problem?

Comment: Deterministic hashing is not difficult, but why are you doing it? If this is for security, SHA1 is insufficient.

Comment: It's problematic to compare floats, even if done indirectly through a hash. Should 0 and 1e-12 really be considered unequal? Can you go in the other direction and coerce the floats to ints? What do these floats actually represent?

Comment: @Reinderien not for security. It's for linking database entries to unique combinations of metadata.

Comment: @Reinderien "Should 0 and 1e-12 really be considered unequal?" Yes, but rounding to a certain precision is under consideration. "Can you go in the other direction and coerce the floats to ints?" No. "What do these floats actually represent?" Arbitrary values. For example, 0.5 millivolt.

Comment: A "less clunky way" would be to use a primary key from the database entries. Or add a sequence number to the entries if there isn't one already.

Comment: @RootTwo I'm not sure I follow, I will provide more context. I have a table A where the rows need to be correlated with metadata. The metadata is given as a dict. I want to save space by not simply putting the data from the metadata-dict into each row of table A, because there are much less valid combinations of metadata than rows in table A. So the idea is to have a table B which stores the metadata, with the primary key in table B being the hash of the dict. Now each row in table A can just store the hash of the corresponding metadata.